# iOS User guidelines at startup

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-interaction

I was wondering is there a way to give the user a small guided tour of the app with small pops exactly above the UI elements indicating what it will do and not using the standard popups which iOS has. 
Something like if an icon is used to post status there should be a small pop up on top of it which tells us it is used to post status and can be closed a standard in in games to introduce the player to their UI.

Comment: Can you point me in that direction please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Open Source library on GitHub that might be interesting for you:

https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView

Edit:
This is another one:
https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/

Comment: that was what i was looking for, but its pretty dull and uninteresting from user interaction point of view. do you know how we can build this     [link](http://mobile-patterns.com/edu) into the application?

Comment: that is not useful in my case but thanx for suggesting it